# Max sum of two consecutive numbers

Tags: java

Suppose we have N numbers and we have to arrange the numbers in such a way that we get the sum of two consecutive numbers as maximum.

For example : 18,20,16,12

Here sum of two consecutive numbers would be (18+20)+(20+16)+(16+12)= 38+36+28=102
But we can arrange the above numbers also like this such that

12,20,18,16

where

(12+20)+(20+18)+(18+16)= 32+38+34=104

Can someone help me with this. I need to write a java program for this.

Comment: `I need to write a java program for this.` ... ideally you can also include the code you have already tried.  Stack Overflow tries to not be a free homework writing service.

Answer (score 2):

If you have *N* numbers that you want to maximize the sum of consecutive numbers

{a, b, c, d, e} ---> ( a + b ) + ( b + c ) + .... ( d + e )

Simplifying that algebraically

( a + 2b + 2c + ... + 2d + e )

To Maximise this, you only need have your lowest value numbers as *a* or *e*

So, if you sort the list Then take the minimum 2 elements, and put one at the end and one ata the front, the internal order doesn't matter.